# JSON manipulation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have json file that contains data. I want to print output like this:

```
jan - male 1 female 2
feb - male 1 female 1
march - male 2 female 2
```

my json file look like this :

```
[
  {
    "id": "qvODYl5PRcN4bR3yotVh",
    "data": {
      "registration_time": "2020-04-30 21:11:21",
      "sex": "Female"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "qvODYl7PucN4bR3yotVh",
    "data": {
      "registration_time": "2020-03-30 21:11:21",
      "sex": "Male"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is full json file https://pastebin.com/Zmy8mNZN

Here is my code so far :

```
global.fetch = require("cross-fetch");

fetch("https://pastebin.com/raw/fvJkWEk5")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(users => {
      var subset = {
        registration_time: users["data"]["registration_time"],
        sex: users["data"]["sex"]
      };
      var sex = subset["sex"];
      var date = new Date(subset["registration_time"]);
      var m = date.getMonth();

      var months = [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "Sept",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec"
      ];
      console.log(months[m] + "  " + sex);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

seemed like a simple task but I'm finding it hard to achieve.

Comment: What specifically are you having issues with?

Comment: Are you trying to make a summary of registrations per month, breaking down by gender?

Comment: @customcommander exactly that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: @DaveNewton I can't get desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass jsonData array as input to the summarize function.

```
function groupByRegistrationDate(array) {
    const months = [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "Sept",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec"
    ];

    return array.reduce((agg, current) => {
        const { registration_time, sex } = current;
        const month = months[new Date(registration_time).getMonth()];
        (agg[month] = agg[month] || []).push(sex.toLowerCase());
        return agg;
    }, {});
}

function preprocess(data) {
    return data.map((entry) => entry.data);
}

function summarize(jsonData) {
    const aggregatedData = groupByRegistrationDate(preprocess(jsonData));
    Object.entries(aggregatedData).forEach(([month, registrations]) => {
        const maleRegs = registrations.filter(x => x === 'male').length;
        const femaleRegs = registrations.length - maleRegs;

        console.log(`${month} - Male ${maleRegs} Female ${femaleRegs}`);
    });
}

summarize(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

to print the data in the above given format use this where json_data is your JSON object

```
var months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "Sept",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];
  var months_data = [
      {
          "female" : 0,
          "male" : 0,
      },
      {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
    {
        "female" : 0,
        "male" : 0,
    },
  ]
  json_data.map((u,i) => {
      months_data[parseInt(u.data.registration_time.split("-")[1]) - 1][u.data.sex.toLowerCase()]++;
  })
  months_data.map((u,i) => {
    console.log(months[i] + "  male " +  u.male + " female " + u.female);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global.fetch = require("cross-fetch");

fetch("https://pastebin.com/raw/fvJkWEk5")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {

    var months = [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "Sept",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec"
    ];

    var data = data.map(users => {

      var subset = {
        registration_time: users["data"]["registration_time"],
        sex: users["data"]["sex"]
      };
      var sex = subset["sex"];
      var date = new Date(subset["registration_time"]);
      var m = date.getMonth();

      return {month: m, sex: sex};
    });

    var uniqueMonths = [];
    var monthlyData = [];

    data.map(x => {
      if(typeof uniqueMonths.find(m => m.month === x.month) === 'undefined') {
        uniqueMonths.push({month: x.month, female: 0, male: 0});
      }

      monthlyData.push({
        month: x.month,
        female: x.sex === 'Female' ? 1: 0,
        male: x.sex === 'Male' ? 1: 0
      });
    });

    uniqueMonths = uniqueMonths.sort((a, b) => a.month-b.month);

    uniqueMonths.map(m => {
      monthlyData.filter(d => d.month === m.month).map(x => {
        m.female += x.female;
        m.male += x.male;
      });

      console.log(`${months[m.month]} - male ${m.male} female ${m.female}`);
    });

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```